# How to combine multiple tar files into a single tar file

Tags: linux, tar

According to gnu documentation, to add one or more archives to the end of another archive, I can use the ‘--concatenate’ operation.

But in my testing, I found that I can't add more than one file at a time.

```
# ls -al
total 724
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     60 Oct 14 17:40 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 32 root root   4096 Oct 14 16:28 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 245760 Oct 14 18:07 1.tar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 245760 Oct 14 18:07 2.tar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 245760 Oct 14 18:07 3.tar
```

```
# tar tvf 1.tar
-rw-r--r-- root/root    238525 2021-10-14 17:28 1.txt
# tar tvf 2.tar
-rw-r--r-- root/root    238525 2021-10-14 17:29 2.txt
# tar tvf 3.tar
-rw-r--r-- root/root    238525 2021-10-14 17:29 3.txt
```

It appears that it only picked up the first parameter and ignored that rest

```
# tar -A -f 1.tar 2.tar 3.tar
# tar tvf 1.tar
-rw-r--r-- root/root    238525 2021-10-14 17:28 1.txt
-rw-r--r-- root/root    238525 2021-10-14 17:29 2.txt
```

Comment: I suggest: `tar itvf 1.tar`

Answer (score 1):

As described in an excellent and comprehensive [Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1098273),

> this is a known bug in gnu tar (reported in August 2008)

Comment: Is there any alternative or workaround that will let me accomplish the same goal (other than to writing a loop and adding it one at a time)

Comment: The link also points to better site for this kind of question.